# How to get this specific user rankings query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, ranking

I've got tbl_items in my user database that I want to sort user rankings on a particular item with certain id (514). I have test data on my dev environment with this set of data:

```
mysql> select * from tbl_items where classid=514;
+---------+---------+----------+
| ownerId | classId | quantity |
+---------+---------+----------+
|       1 |     514 |        3 |
|       2 |     514 |        5 |
|       3 |     514 |       11 |
|       4 |     514 |       46 |
|       5 |     514 |       57 |
|       6 |     514 |        6 |
|       7 |     514 |        3 |
|       8 |     514 |       27 |
|      10 |     514 |        2 |
|      11 |     514 |       73 |
|      12 |     514 |       18 |
|      13 |     514 |       31 |
+---------+---------+----------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

so far so good :) I wrote the following query:

```
set @row=0;

select a.*, @row:=@row+1 as rank 
from (select a.ownerid,a.quantity from tbl_items a 
where a.classid=514) a order by quantity desc;

+---------+----------+------+
| ownerid | quantity | rank |
+---------+----------+------+
|      11 |       73 |    1 |
|       5 |       57 |    2 |
|       4 |       46 |    3 |
|      13 |       31 |    4 |
|       8 |       27 |    5 |
|      12 |       18 |    6 |
|       3 |       11 |    7 |
|       6 |        6 |    8 |
|       2 |        5 |    9 |
|       7 |        3 |   10 |
|       1 |        3 |   11 |
|      10 |        2 |   12 |
+---------+----------+------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

that ranks correctly the users. However in a table with lots of records, I need to do the following:

**1) be able to get small portion of the list, around where the user ranking actually resides, something that would get me the surrounding records, preserving the overall rank:
I tried to do these things with setting a user variable to the ranking of the current user and by using offset and limit, but couldn't preserve the overall ranking.**

This should get me something like the following (for instance ownerId=2 and surroundings limit 5:

```
+---------+----------+------+
| ownerid | quantity | rank |
+---------+----------+------+
|       3 |       11 |    7 |
|       6 |        6 |    8 |
|       2 |        5 |    9 | --> ownerId=2
|       7 |        3 |   10 |
|       1 |        3 |   11 |
+---------+----------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**2) I'd also need another query (preferably single query) that gets me the top 3 places + the ranking of particular user with certain id, preferably with a single query, no matter if he's among the top 3 places or not. I couldn't get this as well**

It would look like the following (for instance ownerId=2 again):

```
+---------+----------+------+
| ownerid | quantity | rank |
+---------+----------+------+
|      11 |       73 |    1 |
|       5 |       57 |    2 |
|       4 |       46 |    3 |
|       2 |        5 |    9 | --> ownerId=2
+---------+----------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Also I'm in a bit of a concern about the performance of the queries on a table with millions of records...
Hope someone helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) 5 entries around a given id.

```
set @row=0;
set @rk2=-1;
set @id=2;

select b.* from (
  select a.*, @row:=@row+1 as rank, if(a.ownerid=@id, @rk2:=@row, -1) as rank2 
  from (
    select a.ownerid,a.quantity
     from tbl_items a 
    where a.classid=514) a
   order by quantity desc) b
where b.rank > @rk2 - 3
limit 5;
```

Though you'll get an extra column `rank2`: you probably want to filter it out by explicit list of columns instead of `b.*`. Maybe it's possible whith a `having` clause rather than an extra nesting.

2) 3 top ranked entries + 1 specific id

```
select b.* from (
  select a.*, @row:=@row+1 as rank 
  from (
    select a.ownerid,a.quantity
    from tbl_items a 
    where a.classid=514) a
  order by quantity desc) b
where b.rank < 4 or b.ownerid=@id
```

Comment: hi man, looks good. However, it gives me "Unknown column 'rank' in 'where clause'" for both queries + there's an extra comma before from in second query...

Comment: Should be better now. Please try it and tell me if there's a problem.

Comment: first query results in the same error, while the second one results in: "right syntax to use near 'having a.rank in (1,2,3) or a.ownerid=@id' at line 1"

Comment: Had to put order by at the end

Comment: hi man. Query 1 works beautifully, however it would get me only 3 results if requested user is #1 ranking... Could it be made possible to select the following 4 users in that case?

Comment: second query results in a single result (ownerid=2,quantity=5,rank=22)

Comment: Sorry, It's laborious. I think I would have to change #1 a lot to always get 5 entries whether the id is in top or bottom pos, but at least it should work when it's in top pos.

Comment: Hi man, yes, they now work great, except for positions that are last or last but one. I'll try to elaborate on this and post later if I figure out how to do it. Thank you !

Comment: you should note that doing 2) in single query and with variables will be much slower (in my case ~100x slower on table 100K users) than just execute 3 queries: select score, name from mytable order by score desc limit 3; $user_score = select score from mytable where user=thisparticularuser; select count(score) from mytable where score > $user_score; Table fields are fake but you get the idea. Do not make database server do all work for you, it is designed to be one of your tools, not all.